# Ionic app works fine on browser but does not open in my phone

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I know this question had been asked before. But all the solution is not worked for me. My ionic application is working well in browser ionic serve --lab. However, when I ionic platform add android and ionic build android. It displays a blank page in my phone. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Do you have logs?

Comment: @Shmuel How to check the log. In my cmd, it just display something like UP-TO-DATE and Build Successful

Comment: Looking for a solution at the same moment for the exact same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see what it is happening you should:

- [Remote Debugging](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/) with Chrome Dev Tools
- Check the Android log with [adb](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/shell.html) with the command `adb logcat` and some filters:

  ```
  adb logcat Cordova:* DroidGap:* CordovaLog:* *:S
  adb logcat Cordova:* DroidGap:* CordovaLog:* *:S CordovaWebView:* Web Console:*
  ```

Answer (score 0):

If you're just seeing a blank white screen on Android, it means that you have an error somewhere in the app. The best way to deal with this situation is to debug the application while using it on your phone. Chrome can help you do that.

Answer (score 0):

What you can connect your phone to your PC, run `ionic run android` in your google chrome and go to the URL `chrome://inspect/#devices` There you can see your device and application logs to see the browser console. There you can identify the error because it is loaded on your phone.